# UITableView : viewForHeaderInSection: not called during reloadData:

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I've set up the tableview with correct delegate and datasource linkages.. the reloadData method calls the datasource and the delegate methods except for `viewForHeaderInSection:`.

Why is that so?

Comment: Is the `heightForHeaderInSection:` implemented?

Comment: Have you set a value for the TableView's `sectionHeaderHeight`?

Answer (score 266):

The use of `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` requires that you also implement `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`. This should return an appropriate non-zero height for the header. Also make sure you do not also implement the `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`. You should only use one or the other (`viewForHeader` or `titleForHeader`).

Comment: Make sure there isn't a typo in the method's signature. One wrong letter will mean it won't be called. Check the case too. Also make sure you are returning 0 from `numberOfSections`.

Comment: everything is correct and compiles correctly.. the issue I wanted to understand is around the timing of when the method is called .. tableView:viewForHeaderInSection is called when the table is just about to be displayed and not as part of the synch execution of [tableview reloadData]

Comment: @maddy OMG Thank you, it's so stupid of me i created my instances but I didn't append to my array

Comment: You can absolutely have both. viewForHeaderInSection: will have precedence over titleForHeaderInSection: The only requirement is that you set estimatedSectionHeaderHeight on your table view with something different than 0, otherwise viewForHeaderInSection: will never get called

Comment: Adding to @romrom's comment: if you have implemented both  `titleForHeaderInSection:` and `viewForHeaderInSection:` and the view returned from the latter is a subclass of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` then its `textLabel.text` is automatically set to the all-caps version of the `titleForHeaderInSection:` string. To prevent this behavior, either don't implement `titleForHeaderInSection:` or use a custom label instead of the inherited `textLabel`.

Comment: I've just encountered a situation where only one of the headers isn't called. The heightForHeaderInSection is called for all sections, but the viewForHeaderInSection is not called for one of the sections. Which one? The one where the included textfield was just edited. Why does it need to be called? Because the editing could cause the section sort to change. When the data is updated, it is sorted, so I want to redisplay ALL sections, including the section just edited. Weirdly, that is the one that is skipped even though height is queried.

Answer (score 43):

The trick is that those two methods belong to different `UITableView` protocols: `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` is a **`UITableViewDataSource`** protocol method, where `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection` belongs to **`UITableViewDelegate`**.

That means:

- If you implement the methods but assign yourself only as the
  `dataSource` for the `UITableView`, your
  `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection` implementation will be ignored.
- `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection` has a higher priority. If you
  implement both of the methods and assign yourself as both the
  `dataSource` and the `delegate` for the `UITableView`, you will
  return the views for section headers but your
  `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` will be ignored.

I have also tried removing `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`; it worked fine and didn't seem to affect the procedures above. But the documentation says that it is required for the `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection` to work correctly; so to be safe it is wise to implement this, as well.

Comment: You made my day!!! Forgot to assign ``UITableViewDelegate`` to ``self``, because I thought, that ``tableView:viewForHeaderInSection`` is a ``UITableViewDataSource`` method. Thank you!

Comment: "tableView:viewForHeaderInSection" is not vital. What's vital is you *somehow* return a height. You could achieve that through either 1. estimate or 2. a hardcoded value or 3. a `titleForHeader` which has an intrinsic size. The intrinsic size is calculated based on the Font Family and size.

Answer (score 29):

@rmaddy has misstated the rule, twice: in reality, `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` does *not* require that you also implement `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`, and also it is perfectly fine to call both `titleForHeader` and `viewForHeader`. I will state the rule correctly just for the record:

The rule is simply that `viewForHeader` will not be called unless you somehow give the header a height. You can do this in any combination of three ways:

- Implement `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`.
- Set the table's `sectionHeaderHeight`.
- Call `titleForHeader` (this somehow gives the header a default height if it doesn't otherwise have one).

If you do none of those things, you'll have no headers and `viewForHeader` won't be called. That's because without a height, the runtime won't know how to resize the view, so it doesn't bother to ask for one.

Comment: From the docs for `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`: " This method only works correctly when `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` is also implemented.".

Comment: Fine. What the docs say, they say. Now experiment. The facts are as I have stated.

Comment: And how can you have both `titleForHeaderInSection` and `viewForHeaderInSection`? The table view will only call one of the two (I forget which gets precedence at the moment).

Comment: Actually there is one more piece of the puzzle, which is that _sometimes_ `viewForHeader` is called _without_ any of those three ways of assigning a height. I have had this happen, where my `viewForHeader` was called and headers showed up just fine, _until one day, with no change on my part, they didn't_. That's when I started experimenting to discover what the minimal requirements are for `viewForHeader` to be called. And now I know. And now so do you.

Comment: If both `titleForHeaderInSection` and `viewForHeaderInSection` are implemented, and assuming `viewForHeaderInSection` returns a UITableViewHeaderFooterView, they will both be called, and in fact this is a perfectly reasonable thing to do.

Comment: Now I tried to implement `titleForHeaderInSection` together with `viewForHeaderInSection` (whereas I only need the view). It works as matt stated but what should `titleForHeaderInSection` return? It only worked for me when returning an empty space. So it's still a compromise because I have to additionaly return things (height or space).

Comment: @matt, do you have any clue for the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665313/getheightforheader-and-getviewforheader-not-called

Comment: @texas No, I don't do xamarin. Adding another level of indirection on top of the Cocoa frameworks would just make my head explode. :)

Comment: :-) Just ignore about xamarin, my question is simply that my implementation always calls `TitleHeader` but not calling `ViewHeight` and `ViewHeader`. What might be reason?

Comment: Any reason you excluded `estimatedSectionHeaderHeight` from your three ways?

Comment: @Honey Look at the date on that answer.

Comment: Ouch/hah. Didn't know. You have look at the date I started developing :) but I guess adding that to the answer won't bother.

Answer (score 24):

Giving `estimatedSectionHeaderHeight` and `sectionHeaderHeight` values fixed my problem.
e.g.,
`self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 100
self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Comment: My issue started after upgrading to Swift 3.1. This solution fixed it.

Comment: @pbuchheit Apple Docs says it is available from iOS 7.0+, please have a look here, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614957-estimatedsectionheaderheight

Comment: @Sharukh Mastan Looks like you are correct. For some reason I was getting a warning when I tried using that property, but it went away after doing a clean build.

Answer (score 8):

Going off rmaddy 's answer, I was trying to hide the Header view and was returning 0.0f for "tableView:heightForHeaderInSection" and a 0 height View from `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection` .

After changing from `return 1.0f` to `return 0.0f` in `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection`, the delegate method `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection` was indeed called.

Turns out my desired effect works without having to use "tableView:heightForHeaderInSection"; but this may be useful to others who are having an issue getting "tableView:heightForHeaderInSection" delegate method called.

Answer (score 7):

You should implement `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` and set the height for the header >0.

This delegate method goes along with the `viewForHeaderInSection:` method.

I hope this helps.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
         return 40;
}
```

Comment: Have you tested that your answer actually works?
Becaus eif you read carefully then it's stated that initially the viewForHeaderInSection is called.
It's not called only when the table is reloaded!

Answer (score 6):

It's worth briefly noting that if your implementation of `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` returns `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, then `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` will not be called.

`UITableViewAutomaticDimension` assumes that a standard `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` will be used that is populated with the delegate method `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`.

From comments in the `UITableView.h`:

> Returning this value from `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` or `tableView:heightForFooterInSection:` results in a height that fits the value returned from `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` or `tableView:titleForFooterInSection:` if the title is not nil.

Comment: if you set ``estimatedSectionHeaderHeight``to some value, ``tableView:viewForHeaderInSection`` will be called (similarly to how auto dimensions for rows works)

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Back at 7.1 [this subtlety of estimated height was important for cells](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31558458/2547229), so might have been the case for headers too – but it's not terribly relevant now!

Answer (score 4):

I've just had an issue with headers not showing for **iOS 7.1**, but working fine with later releases I have tested, explicitly with 8.1 and 8.4.

For the exact same code, 7.1 was *not* calling any of the section header delegate methods at all, including: `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` and `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`.

After experimentation, I found that **removing** this line from my `viewDidLoad` made headers re-appear for 7.1 and did not impact other versions I tested:

```
// _Removing_ this line _fixed_ headers on 7.1
self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 80;
```

… so, there seems to be some kind of conflict there for 7.1, at least.

Answer (score 4):

Same issue occured with me but as I was using **automatic height calculation** from **xCode 9**, I cannot give any explicit height value as mentioned above. After some experimentation I **got solution**, we have to override this method as,

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
      return 44.0f;
}
```

Although I have **checked** both options

1. **Automatic Height Calculation**
2. **Automatic Estimated Height Calculation**

from **storyboard** as apple says, but still I got this weird error.

**Please Note**: This Error was shown only on **IOS-10** version not on **IOS-11** version. Maybe it's a bug from xCode. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `viewForHeaderInSection` does not get called is for one of two reasons:

Either you did not set up your `UITableViewDelegate`, or
you set up your `UITableViewDelegate` incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've found (**Swift 4**)
(thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28488181/428981) on another question)

Whether I used titleForHeaderInSection or viewForHeaderInSection - it wasn't that they weren't getting called when the tableview was scrolled and new cells were being loaded, but any font choices I made for the headerView's textLabel were only appearing on what was initially visible on load, and not as the table was scrolled.

The fix was willDisplayHeaderView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    if let header = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
        header.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: yourFont, size: 42)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have created header view using `UITableviewCell` and returning the cell in `viewForHeaderInSection` like this

```
return cell
```

changed this to

```
return cell.contentView
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case

```
viewForHeaderInSection
```

was implemented in a derived class far far away that was not bothering to daisy into superclass.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was cause I did not implement:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes setting `tableview.delegate` or `datasource = nil` in the `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:` methods can cause this issue.  Make sure not to do this...

Answer (score -1):

I had cut & paste the following two methods from a Swift 2 project into my Swift 3 project which were never called because in Swift 3 these methods must have "-" before the first parameter name.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44.0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: B2BTrolleyHeaderFooterView.reuseIdentifier) as! B2BTrolleyHeaderFooterView        
    return headerView
}
```