# Troubles with changing the font size in UITableViewHeaderFooterView

Tags: ios, uitableview

Here is the problem,

I subclass a UITableViewHeaderFooterView and want to change the font size:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.8 alpha:1.0];
        //the font is not working
        self.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
        NSLog(@"aaa%@", self.textLabel.font);
    }
    return self;
}
```

The color stuff works fine, but the font didn't change, so I log the dequeue:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UITableViewHeader *headerView = [self.tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:MWDrawerHeaderReuseIdentifier];
    headerView.textLabel.text = self.sectionTitles[@(section)];
    NSLog(@"bbb%@", headerView.textLabel.font);
    return headerView;
}
```

The font still goes right in here, so I log in `didLayoutsubviews`:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *head = [self.tableView headerViewForSection:0];
    NSLog(@"ccc%@", head.textLabel.font);
}
```

and the font size is magically CHANGED back to the default!!! But I didn't do anything between there, and If I change the font size again in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, the font becomes right.

It drives me CRAZY!!!

And I do the same font changing when subclass the cell, and it works fine! so can anyone tell me what's going on? Thanks!

Here is the log:

```
2014-02-09 16:02:03.339 InternWell[33359:70b] aaa<UICTFont: 0x8da4290> font-family: ".HelveticaNeueInterface-M3"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 20.00pt

2014-02-09 16:02:03.339 InternWell[33359:70b] bbb<UICTFont: 0x8da4290> font-family: ".HelveticaNeueInterface-M3"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 20.00pt

2014-02-09 16:02:03.341 InternWell[33359:70b] aaa<UICTFont: 0x8da4290> font-family: ".HelveticaNeueInterface-M3"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 20.00pt

2014-02-09 16:02:03.342 InternWell[33359:70b] bbb<UICTFont: 0x8da4290> font-family: ".HelveticaNeueInterface-M3"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 20.00pt

2014-02-09 16:02:03.343 InternWell[33359:70b] ccc<UICTFont: 0x8d22650> font-family: ".HelveticaNeueInterface-MediumP4"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 14.00pt

2014-02-09 16:02:03.343 InternWell[33359:70b] ccc<UICTFont: 0x8d22650> font-family: ".HelveticaNeueInterface-MediumP4"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 14.00pt
```

Comment: Same issue even without subclassing UITableViewHeaderFooterView, a font that is set gets reset by the time the view is presented. Checked on iOS 9.3.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It doesn't seem like the right place to put it, but you can change the font in the `layoutSubviews` method of your `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` subclass and it will apply properly.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // Font
    self.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
}
```

Comment: `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` does naughty things in `-layoutSubviews`, including changing the color of the `textLabel`. I wouldn’t be surprised if it changes the font as well. This was the workaround I arrived at as well, but it seems like a bug.

Comment: There must be a better way to do this - `layoutSubviews` is supposed to only contain layout, it can be called several times in a single rendering loop, and as such, it's not recommended to place anything other than layout here; I assume the better approach is to either create a custom title label, or update the font in `willDisplayHeaderView`.

Answer (score 28):

You could implement *tableView:willDisplayHeaderView* and change the font in kind of this way:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(section == ...)
    {
        UITableViewHeaderFooterView *headerView = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
        NSAttributedString *headerText = ... ;
        headerView.textLabel.attributedText = headerText;
    }
}
```

Comment: Much nicer solution than the selected answer. I just did this in Swift, works great (and no need to subclass):  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
  if let header = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
   header.textLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(22.0)
  }
 }

Comment: I wouldn't say this is nicer at all. You're badly separating concerns by modifying the layout of a view ~outside~ the file in which you are describing the rest of the view's layout. Very bad code smell for me.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like `textLabel` `font` is ignored even in iOS 11.

An alternative solution (Swift 4) is to use a custom label. It shouldn't be difficult if you already have a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` subclass.

```
class MyTableViewHeader: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    let customLabel = UILabel()

    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        customLabel.frame = contentView.bounds
    }

    func setup() {
        customLabel.textColor = UIColor(white: 0.8, alpha: 1)
        customLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
        contentView.addSubview(customLabel)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one a solution in **Swift** - the idea here is that we have a subclass of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` called `SNStockPickerTableHeaderView`; it exposes a method called, `configureTextLabel()` that when called, sets the font and the color of the text label. We call this method only after the title has been set, that is from, `willDisplayHeaderView`, and the font gets correctly set.

```
// MARK: UITableViewDelegate

func tableView(tableView:UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view:UIView, forSection section:Int) {
  if let headerView:SNStockPickerTableHeaderView = view as? SNStockPickerTableHeaderView {
    headerView.configureTextLabel()
  }
}

func tableView(tableView:UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section:Int) -> UIView? {
  var headerView:SNStockPickerTableHeaderView? = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier(kSNStockPickerTableHeaderViewReuseIdentifier) as? SNStockPickerTableHeaderView
  if (headerView == nil) {
    headerView = SNStockPickerTableHeaderView(backgroundColor:backgroundColor,
      textColor:primaryTextColor,
      lineSeparatorColor:primaryTextColor)
  }
  return headerView!
}
```

And here is the custom `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

private let kSNStockPickerTableHeaderViewLineSeparatorHeight:CGFloat = 0.5
private let kSNStockPickerTableHeaderViewTitleFont = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Light", size:12)

let kSNStockPickerTableHeaderViewReuseIdentifier:String = "stock_picker_table_view_header_reuse_identifier"

class SNStockPickerTableHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

  private var lineSeparatorView:UIView?
  private var textColor:UIColor?

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  // We must implement this, since the designated init of the parent class
  // calls this by default!
  override init(frame:CGRect) {
    super.init(frame:frame)
  }

  init(backgroundColor:UIColor, textColor:UIColor, lineSeparatorColor:UIColor) {
    super.init(reuseIdentifier:kSNStockPickerTableHeaderViewReuseIdentifier)
    contentView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    self.textColor = textColor
    addLineSeparator(textColor)
  }

  // MARK: Layout

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let lineSeparatorViewY = CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds) - kSNStockPickerTableHeaderViewLineSeparatorHeight
    lineSeparatorView!.frame = CGRectMake(0,
      lineSeparatorViewY,
      CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds),
      kSNStockPickerTableHeaderViewLineSeparatorHeight)
  }

  // MARK: Public API

  func configureTextLabel() {
    textLabel.textColor = textColor
    textLabel.font = kSNStockPickerTableHeaderViewTitleFont
  }

  // MARK: Private

  func addLineSeparator(lineSeparatorColor:UIColor) {
    lineSeparatorView = UIView(frame:CGRectZero)
    lineSeparatorView!.backgroundColor = lineSeparatorColor
    contentView.addSubview(lineSeparatorView!)
  }
}
```

Here is the result, see section header for, "Popular Stocks":

[image]