# UITapGesture in UITableview header

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios8, uigesturerecognizer

I trying to use expandable tableview in swift. So I added Gesture to header in  tableview, but it does not recognising. Kindly guide me. Just cross check my coding.

MY CODING IS BELOW:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let vvv = tableView.headerViewForSection(section)

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
        tap.delegate = self
        vvv?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        return vvv
    }


    func handleTap(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        if(gestureRecognizer.state == .Ended)
        {
            println("SECTION PRESSED") //NOT ENTERING TO THIS BLOCK
        }     
    }
```

Comment: Is the viewForHeaderInSection method getting called?

Comment: Is user interaction on? I haven't done it with gesture recognizer, but I remember doing it with custom UIView subclass and overwritting the touchesBegan method, then telling the delegate that the view was tapped.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078725/uitableview-viewforheaderinsection-not-called-during-reloaddata

Comment: hi all! viewForHeaderInSection, this method is getting called. But, no response. How to solve this?

Comment: hi Lord! how did you do that? Can you explain it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Swift 4 you can add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the header view:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let headerView = UIView()

    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(headerTap))
    headerView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

    return headerView
}

@objc func headerTap() {
    // Tap action
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I did it this way.

First, make a UITableViewCell class with a "headerCellSection" variable (or whatever you want to call it for that matter).

```
import UIKit

class HeaderCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var headerCellSection:Int?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Add the cell to "viewForHeaderInSection":

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("headerCell") as! HeaderCellTableViewCell

        return headerCell
    }
```

Send the cell's section to the previously declared variable and add the tap gesture recogniser to the cell. The code should look something like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("headerCell") as! HeaderCellTableViewCell

        // Send section
        headerCell.headerCellSection = section

        // Add gesture
        let headerTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
        headerTapGesture.addTarget(self, action: "myAction:")
        headerCell.addGestureRecognizer(headerTapGesture)

    return headerCell
}
```

Then add the action. In the action you can access the view that has the tap gesture target. There you can access tour "headerCellSection" value and voila!

```
func myAction (sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    // Get the view
    let senderView = sender.view as! HeaderCellTableViewCell

    // Get the section
    let section = senderView.headerCellSection

    print(section)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it by adding the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the `contentView` of the headerView. Example:

`headerCell.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(headerTapped)))`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old question to give an answer. But none of the answers accepted, I will give another simple solution.

After I read original question, I thought the author do not want a custom created section header. That's why he was trying to use following code.

```
let vvv = tableView.headerViewForSection(section)
```

But I'm sure you will get a null value for *vvv* in the above code snippet. If user wants to access the default view, he can do it as below.

```
tableView.register(UITableViewHeaderFooterView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: sectionHeaderIdentifier)
```

Above registration, I did in my viewDidLoad() function. Then use below code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let sectionView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: sectionHeaderIdentifier)!
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(sectionHeaderTapped))
    sectionView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    return sectionView
}
```

Above function will create the default view for your table section headers with the tap gesture attribute enabled.