# titleForHeaderInSection not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've created classes both to be the `dataSource` and `delegate` of a table view. While the cells are appearing properly, I am finding that this method:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

is not getting called.

What would be a reason for this?

All I could think of was verifying that I did not implement:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and I DID implement:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`
```

Is there any other reason the method would not be called?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableView : viewForHeaderInSection: not called during reloadData:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078725/uitableview-viewforheaderinsection-not-called-during-reloaddata)

Comment: @shallowThought thanks for pointing that out. I have clarified my question to indicate that I did implement heightForHeaderInSection.

Comment: have you implementedhttps://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614860-numberofsections ?

Comment: Are other data source methods being called? Do you have at least 1 section in your table view?