# TableViewHeader with dynamic height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, height

I have a `UITableViewHeader` which contains a `UILabel` (dynamic height - can be one line or mulitple lines) and a custom `UICollectionView` which shows a UILabel in each `UICollectionViewCell`. Depending on which device is used, these `UICollectionViewCells` can span over one line or they can be on two or three lines. That all doesn't matter that much.

My problem is in the `heightForHeaderInSection` method. As this gets called before the frame is set (`print(headerView.frame.height)` returns 0.0), I can't properly return the correct height. I am trying to access the headerView.frame.height so it can be set dynamically, but I fail to do so. I have looked into `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, but then I would have to store it as a `CGFloat` and force `heightForHeaderInSection` to be called again.

I am pretty sure there must be a way to do this more easily. I also tried looking in to `UITableView.automaticDimension`, but this hasn't brought me to the resolution either. Any suggestions?

Comment: this might help [https://stackoverflow.com/a/15078805/6654562]

Comment: Are you using viewforheaderinsection method to create the header view?

Comment: Yes. But I am now looking into setting the tableHeaderView because it should only show on top and there is only one section. However, some problem, I seem unable to find "where" to set the dynamic height.